# Prevent itemize from creating newline at end of list

Tags: spacing, lists, itemize, enumitem

I'm using the itemize environment with the enumitem package, and one of the issues I'm having is that the itemize environment seems to create a newline, or at least add vertical spacing at the end of the environment.

How can I suppress this newline?

Comment: Are you looking for [Inline lists](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures#Inline_lists)??

Answer (score 7):

The list-like environments (`enumerate`, `itemize`, and `description`) add a vertical space equal to `\topsep + \parskip + (possibly) \partopsep` before and after the list. You can suppress those spaces using the corresponding `enumitem` keys; an example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt]
  \item First.
  \item Second.
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This appears to be be right, but I don't believe enumitem allows you to define parsep. Adding a \setlength\parsep{0pt} inside the itemize environment didn't seem to solve things. How can I set the value of parskip for only the itemize environment?

Comment: @Varun Madiath: you can change the value using the `parsep` key, as in `\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt]`. You can kill all extra vertical space with the `nolistsep` option.

Comment: My apologies, I was referring to parskip in my earlier comment. How can I set the parskip for the itemize environment.

Comment: @Varun Madiath: the value of `\parskip` inside `itemize` is controlled by the `parsep` key of `enumitem`; however, you can always change it manually by adding something like `\setlength\parskip{10pt}` inside `itemize`, just before the first `\item` command.

Comment: @Varun Madiath: If the problem with the list persists, please add a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) to your original question, illustrating the problem.